# En el DataFrame de la foto, ¿cómo podría cambiar los valores '...' para que Python me los guarde como NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quiero sustituir el string `...` por valores de Not A Number (NaN). He probado a hacer df=df.replace({'...':NaN}) pero no funciona.
Gracias!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye el código que tienes y lo que has intentado e investigado para que podamos ayudarte. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas ser ayudado más facilmente por la comunidad.

Comment: Reconstruí tu data, pero sí me funciona, puedes mostrar todo el código relevante? (imports, definición del dataframe y el error, si tienes alguno). Ayudaría también si pones la data original en un bloque de código

Comment: Ya funciona! Me faltaba por añadir la librería Pandas del siguiente modo: df=df.replace({'...':pd.NaN})

Comment: Máster IA de la VIU?

Comment: No, pero planteándome hacer un máster de IA